# Matlab parallel computation

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

Is it mandatory to have parallel computing toolbox to use all the cores of my CPU?

Is it possible to do the make a computation to run on all the cores of one single CPU without any toolbox?

Comment: A lot of the functions will multithread themselves. I don't have an exhaustive list of which ones do (matrix mult, fft, ...) and they seem to cap out at 16 threads for me. No idea if that's a compile-time option or what. You can always write your own mex code and use pthreads. I do that a lot to get real speed when I need it.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 MATLAB's default behaviour is to consider only the physical cores on your system, not hyperthreaded cores. Check `feature('numcores')` to see what it should be using.

Comment: In Mathematica I can parallelize a computation by using the parallel counterpart. For example, `Table` and `ParallelTable` both create a matrix but the latter is parallelized. Is there such a thing in Matlab without paying for extra license?
As I understood it seems that Matlab commands use parallel computation by their default and I cannot choose to turn this feature off or on. Is this right?
I really don't know anything about Matlab. It just seems it is able to do minimization faster than MMA so that's why I am planning to use it.

Comment: @yashar You can read about an idea [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1). MIT's LL also put together what can only honestly be called a hack to get around matlab's dearth of free mutlithreading support called [pMatlab](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/cybersec/softwaretools/pmatlab/pmatlab.html). There's more info out there that you can find with a search engine.